# Hide and show Parts in Handler

Tags: handler, rcp, e4

I'm trying to hide and show a part in the execute Method of my Handler.
But I just can't seem to get it to work as I intended. 
When accesssing the PartService I get an 
"Application does not have an active window" exception.

Here's my code for hiding the part

```java
@Execute
@Inject
public void execute(final EPartService partService) {
    final MPart part = partService.findPart("mypart");
    partService.hidePart(part);
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you calling this from a dialog?

Comment: I'm calling it inside my handler

Comment: Yes, but how are you invoking the handler (from a menu, a dialog, a key shortcut, ....)? If you call the command from a dialog or something like that you get this error.

Comment: it is invoked by a Handled Tool Item, which signals the command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't specify `@Inject` on your methods you only need `@Execute`.

Using `@Inject` is causing the code to run when the handler is first created before the application window exists.

So just:

```java
@Execute
public void execute(final EPartService partService) {
```

Comment: thanks a lot. That solved the problem. When should I add @Inject then. I thought I would need it to inject something in my method.

Comment: `@Execute` includes doing injection. `@Inject` on methods is only used if you want the injector to look at the method when the class is created (not the case for handlers). Don't forget to accept the question.